# how do i have sympy yield `{1, 2}` given an positive integer `x < 3`

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to solve an inequality using `sympy.solve`, here is the code

```py
from sympy import Symbol, solve
x = Symbol('x', positive=True, integer=True)
ineq1 = x - 3 < 0
solution = solve((ineq1), x)
print(solution)
```

The program above yields `x < 3`. The result makes sense though, i'd like to get a set that consists of 2 integers 1 and 2, `{1, 2}`.
how do i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A univariate inequality can be handled by Sets and Set intersection can limit the result to positive integers:

```py
>>> from sympy import Range, oo, S, And
...
>>> ineq1.as_set().intersection(Range(1,oo))
{1, 2}
```

You can also replace `Range(1,oo)` with `S.Naturals`. You can also use a compound expression and intersect its set with `S.Integers`:

```py
>>> And(x>0,x<3).as_set().intersection(S.Integers)
{1, 2}
```